# .TFW for georeferencing output rasters?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, gdal, georeferencing

I am running base image pairs with similar extents (image1.TIF and image2.TIF) through a command line tool and the resulting raster (result.TIF) comes out without the georeference. I read that generating the .tfw file of either image1.TIF or image2.TIF then renaming this .tfw file into result.TFW and placing this into the directory where result.TIF is stored will provide result.TIF with the appropriate spatial reference. I generated the .TFW file with GDAL. However, pasting this .TFW file into the directory doesn’t produce the desired outcome. I choose not to use the georeferencing tool within GIS because it will warp the image.

Any tips on how to go about this?

I tried this with ArcMap 10.4.1 and QGIS 3.16.

Comment: It should work with result.tif and result.tfw if result.tfw is correct. Add the contents your .tfw as plain text into your question. And if the result is not the desired, describe what is wrong with the result.

Comment: Can you post your .tfw file here?  There is a good explanation here -https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/204174165-TFW-World-File-Values.  This will control the scale, rotation and position of the image.  You will also need the correct projection.  Which could be a .prj file or you can pick the correct projection in QGIS.  You could import the image and georeference it in QGIS and then export the .tif .tfw files to compare to what you are getting. https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: Hi everyone! Got it to work without fussing with separate files. Used this command: gdal_translate ORIGINAL.TIF -a_srs EPSG:XXXX -a_ullr ULX ULY LRX LRY OUTPUT.TIF (where ULX is upper left X coordinate in decimals and so on and so forth)

Comment: @Khelly Kindly post it as answer, if your problem is solved.